# error specified index is not a column of x (as_tbl_time)

Tags: r, tibble

I am trying to use `as_tbl_time` but I am receiving the error in the title.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dates <- c("01/01/18 1:01:10 PM" ,"01/01/18 1:10:10 PM")
vals <- c(100, 200)

df <- data.frame(dates, vals)

df$dates <- dmy_hms(df$dates)

df <- as_tbl_time(df, index = df$dates)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibbletime/versions/0.1.1/topics/as_tbl_time):

> index    The bare column name of the column to be used as the index.

So you just need the column name:  `tibbletime::as_tbl_time(df, index = dates)`

Not `df$`.

Comment: Thanks!I missed that!